# Some signal processing /FFT questions

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, accelerometer, fft

I need some help confirming some basic DSP steps. I'm in the process of implementing some smartphone accelerometer sensor signal processing software, but I've not worked in DSP before.

My program collects accelerometer data in real time at 32 Hz. The output should be the principal frequencies of the signal.

My specific questions are:

1. From the real-time stream, I am collecting a 256-sample window with 50% overlap, as I've read in the literature. That is, I add in 128 samples at a time to fill up a 256-sample window. Is this a correct approach?
2. The first figure below shows one such 256-sample window. The second figure shows the sample window after I applied a Hann/Hamming [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). I've read that applying a window function is a typical approach, so I went ahead and did it. Should I be doing so?
3. The third window shows the power spectrum (?) from the output of an FFT library. I am really cobbling together bits and pieces I've read. Am I correct in understanding that the spectrum goes up to 1/2 the sampling rate (in this case 16 Hz, since my sampling rate is 32 Hz), and the value of each spectrum point is spectrum[i] = sqrt(real[i]^2 + imaginary[i]^2)? Is this right?
4. Assuming what I did in question 3 is correct, is my understanding right that the third figure shows principal frequencies of about 3.25 Hz and 8.25 Hz? I know from collecting the data that I was running at about 3 Hz, so the spike at 3.25 Hz seems right. So there must be some noise other other factors causing the (erroneous) spike at 8.25 Hz. Are there any filters or other methods I can use to smooth away this and other spikes? If not, is there a way to determine "real" spikes from erroneous spikes?

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the data? Shaking your phone? Do you get the 8Hz with a different run? without the window function?  Your data seems quite clean, so I don't think the window function is necessary, but the data would probably not be as nice in the real world so it might be needed.

Comment: You can kind of see the 8Hz in your original data: they are the sharp little peaks, some with quite a large amplitude.  Any idea how they appeared? (related to question above about you generated the data.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the 8.25 spike is "erroneous" as you've said. How did you get this data?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing all the right things - I'm a little concerned about the large DC (0 Hz) spike though - are you sure you've interpreted the bin ordering of your FFT output correctly ?

Comment: @Paul R the window function (kind of like the first half of a sine function) is spread over the 8 seconds of his sample.  Wouldn't that generate a huge signal at 1/16 Hz?

Comment: @toto: I generated the data from my Android phone when I placed it into my front-right pocket, so the figures show real data. The phone generates {x,y,z} acceleration values, and I calculate the vector magnitude and write it out at 32 Hz.

Comment: @Paul R: I am actually not sure about the binning since I am new to DSP and FFTs. I am sampling at 32 Hz, and my input into the FFT is a 256-value array. The output of the FFT are two 128-value arrays, apparently one for real (cosine) and one for imaginary (sine). So am I correct in understanding that the binning results in each bin being 32 Hz/256 wide (or equivalently, with a Nyquist frequency of 32/2=16, 16 Hz/ 128 wide)?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser OK.  I thought maybe you were using some turn table or weird apparatus which you knew was doing 3Hz, but you are just walking at around 3 steps/s.  I also thought it was a graph of displacement, not acceleration.  The little peaks could be lateral movement of the phone caught in the fabric.  You could try for fun holding it "steadily" in your swinging hand while walking to see how cleaner the signal can be.  Maybe the hardware has some limitation and it seems noisy if you sample it with too short a time interval.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for your FFT - normally there is only one real value for 0 Hz and one for Fs/2 - all other frequencies are complex pairs. Also, are you zeroing the imaginary part of your FFT input ? (Or is it a real-to-complex FFT ?)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Try removing the window function.  I'm pretty sure you'll lose the big peak at 1/16 Hz.

Comment: You do definitely want to window the data: otherwise you will get erroneous frequency artifacts from the sudden start and finish of the signal. The peak at 0Hz is simply the DC offset of the signal: it is not centred around the origin. Basically you are doing everything correctly and your assumptions about the complex output and resulting frequencies are right.

Comment: OK, I had not noticed that the data is not zeroed, so you do get an offset peak at 0 Hz.  But that made me think that you have some **serious issue** since you are analyzing the absolute value of the acceleration.  It's like analyzing the absolute value of a sine: you would get double the frequency plus some artifact frequencies.

Comment: @toto: I understand see why I might get 'double the frequency' since the x,y,z acceleration components can be positive and negative. The problem is that I don't have a gyroscope in my phone, so I don't know how the phone is oriented when it's in my front pocket. I've seen some papers where people just calculate the acceleration vector's magnitude, so that is what I did.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Maybe you should check those papers again to see if don't have some extra steps.  There must be solutions elsewhere too; I'm sure it happens often that only the magnitude of signal is known.  Or maybe you just have to interpret the frequency differently; it's definitely not your walking frequency.

Answer (score 1):

1. Making a decision on sample size and overlap is always a compromise between frequency accuracy and timeliness: the bigger the sample, the more FFT bins and hence absolute accuracy, but it takes longer. I'm guessing you want regular updates on the frequency you're detecting, and absolute accuracy is not *too* important: so a 256 sample FFT seems a pretty good choice. Having an overlap will give a higher resolution on the same data, but at the expense of processing: again, 50% seems fine.
2. Applying a window will stop frequency artifacts appearing due to the abrupt start and finish of the sample (you are effectively applying a square window if you do nothing). A Hamming window is fairly standard as it gives a good compromise between having sharp signals and low side-lobes: some windows will reject the side-lobes better (multiples of the detected frequency) but the detected signal will be spread over more bins, and others the opposite. On a small sample size with the amount of noise you have on your signal, I don't think it really matters much: you might as well stick with a Hamming window.
3. Exactly right: the power spectrum is the square-root of the sum of the squares of the complex values. Your assumption about the Nyquist frequency is true: your scale will go up to 16Hz. I assume you are using a real FFT algorithm, which is returning 128 complex values (an FFT will give 256 values back, but because you are giving it a real signal, half will be an exact mirror image of the other), so each bin is 16/128 Hz wide. It is also common to show the power spectrum on a log scale, but that's irrelevant if you're just peak detecting.
4. The 8Hz spike really is there: my guess is that a phone in a pocket of a moving person is more than a 1st order system, so you are going to have other frequency components, but should be able to detect the primary. You *could* filter it out, but that's pointless if you are taking an FFT: just ignore those bins if you are sure they are erroneous.

You seem to be getting on fine. The only suggestion I would make is to develop some longer time heuristics on the results: look at successive outputs and reject short-term detected signals. Look for a principal component and see if you can track it as it moves around.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a few of your questions:

Yes, you should be applying a window function. The idea here is that when you start and stop sampling a real-world signal, what you're doing anyway is applying a sharp rectangular window. Hann and Hamming windows are much better at reducing frequencies you don't want, so this is a good approach.

Yes, the strongest frequencies are around 3 and 8 Hz. I don't think the 8 Hz spike is erroneous. With such a short data set you almost certainly can't control the exact frequencies your signal will have.

Answer (score 0):

Some insight on question 4 (from staring at accelerometer signals of people running for months of my life):

Are you running this analysis on a single accelerometer axis channel or are you combining them to create the magnitude of acceleration? If you are interested in the overall magnitude of acceleration of signal, then you should combine x y z such as mag_acc = sqrt((x - 0g_offset)^2 + (y - 0g_offset)^2 + (z - 0g_offset)^2). This signal should be at 1g when the device is still. If you are only looking at a single axis, then you will get components from the dominant running motion and also from the orientation of the phone changing contributing to your signal (because the contribution from gravity will be transitioning around). So if the phone orientation is moving around while you are running from how you are holding it, it can contribute a significant amount to the signal, but the magnitude will not show the orientation changes as much. A person running should have a really clean dominant frequency at the persons step rate.